# ggplot2 cannot display legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I make a legend appear and theme it for the following `ggplot2`?

The `ggplot2` code is:

```
   ggplot(data=df, environment=environment()) + ylab("YVAR") + xlab("XVAR") +
         #Actuals with dots
         geom_line( aes( x = Ratio, y = value), colour='#8EA5B7', size = 1.5) + 
         geom_point(aes(x=Ratio,y=value)) +

         #Line for the predictive model with dots
         geom_line(aes( x = Ratio, y = p), colour='#DC8772', size = 3) + 
         geom_point(aes(x=Ratio,y=p)) +

         #labels for the actual points
         geom_text(aes( x = Ratio, y = value, label = Total), size = 5) +

         # 3 standard devs max limit
         geom_line(aes( x = Ratio, y = sigma3 ), linetype = 'dashed' ) +

         # 3 standard devs min limit
         geom_line(aes( x = Ratio, y = sigma3m ), linetype = 'dashed') +

         # code for the formula
         geom_text(aes( x = 0.01, y = 0.5, label = my_label), colour="black", size=5, parse = TRUE) +

         #scale variable
         scale_colour_manual(values=c("Actual Readings", "Predictive Model")) + 

         # change background colour
         theme_bw()
```

I tried to mess around with theme but it wasn't working.
In the legend I just want entries for the `geom_line` not for the `geom_text` and the `geom_points`.

at the moment it looks like this:

[image: current chart]

Comment: Can you include the output of this code or at least include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can run the code to see what the output is? I really can't tell what you're trying to change.

Comment: this is from someone else's shiny app which I am trying to reverse engineer and reformat. is there a way to extract data structures from within a running app?